# PostGIS clipping raster with the same color band as the orignal raster

Tags: postgis, raster

I am trying to clip a raster so that the clipped raster would have the same minimum and maximum values for the color band as the original raster.

For example if i clip the raster with this command:

```
create table clipped AS SELECT 
ST_Clip(rast,ST_MakePolygon(ST_GeomFromText ('LINESTRING(424920 
7370964, 
424920 7371476,425432 7371476,425432  7370964,424920 7370964) ')) ) FROM original;
```

I get the following result:

[image]

So the clipped raster has band minium value as 0 and maxium value as 20. Instead of that, i want it to be exactly same as the 'original' raster: from 0 to 33.

I am new for PostGIS, but i have tried to find an answer for a while to this question but i haven't found anything. I have tried the functions like ST_Reclass but with no success. What is the proper way to do this with PostGIS?

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 0):

#### Why is that happening?

The reason that your range changes is because your maximum value (33 in your case) is not contained within the area you clipped. This is not a bad thing, its just a fact. It's not a PostGIS thing, its just a clipping thing.

#### Can we find a solution?

I'm guessing that the *real* problem you want solved is that the two rasters look very different in QGIS. That's really easy to fix! I'll show you how with some example data.

---

#### Exmaple Data

Here's what we're starting with:

[Link to image because I don't have enough rep to embed an image yet, I guess...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BdbK.png)

1. Double click on the "clipped" layer to open up the "Layer Properties" window and select the Style tab from the list on the left side of the window
2. Locate the text window for "Max" and change it to 33 to match your original raster. [This picture may help.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhhm5.png) It's worth noting that you may run into a case where your Minimum is different in the clipped raster as well like it is here.  You can adjust that in the same fashion.
3. Apply your changes and watch them work!